# Regex matching of substrings separated by max N words

Tags: regex

I've done extensive googling, but I was not able to find a working expression.  What I mean is to match this metaexpression:

```
Blah Blah Blah, I'm looking for [max N words] player
```

In other words, I need to match:

```
Even these days I'm looking for a couple of players
I'm looking for an experienced player
I'm looking here and there to find a good player  <--- Must not match!
I'm looking for a player
```

and so on...

As you may see I'm not counting characters, but words.

N will probably be 5 in my case.

I don't need to return, just need to check if this n-gram pattern is found in the strings.

**EDIT:**
Edited the third line (the one without the 'for') for clarification

Comment: Why you want to match line no 3? It has no `for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details will depend on which regex flavor you are using. For those that support it, you can search for 1-N instances of an expression, use the `{1,N}` format. For example, using this test file:

```
Even these days I'm looking for a couple of players
I'm looking for an experienced player
I'm looking here and there to find a good player
I'm looking for a player
I'm looking for too many words here, it should not match player
```

Using GNU `grep` to illustrate, with a maximum number of 3:

1. Basic Regular Expressions (BRE)

```
    $ grep -o "I'm looking for \([^[:blank:]]* \)\{1,3\}players*" file 
    I'm looking for a couple of players
    I'm looking for an experienced player
    I'm looking for a player
```

2. Extended Regular Expressions (ERE):

```
 $ grep -oE "I'm looking for ([^\s]* ){1,3}players*" file 
 I'm looking for a couple of players
 I'm looking for an experienced player
 I'm looking for a player
```

Comment: @M42 yes, it isn't a quantifier _in PCREs_ but I'm not using PCREs. While it is not allowed explicitly in the POSIX specs for [ERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04) and [BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03), it is also not disallowed and it does work on the implementations I am familiar with. Anyway, I changed to `{1,N}` just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something along the lines you are looking for?

```
.*(I'm looking for) (.*) (player{1}s?)
```

http://regex101.com/r/zT0qR4/1

I saw on some lines you had player and in other players, and also as Avinash says, do you want to match line #3 as well?

You can capture the words you are looking for within capture groups $2. Or you can just add ?= to the other groups to make them non-capture.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the content within that you could use a regex like this:

```
(?<=looking for)(.*)(?=player)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/qZ4jR9/1)**

[image]

The match content will be:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [31-44] ` a couple of `
MATCH 2
1.  [67-83] ` an experienced `
MATCH 3
1.  [154-157]   ` a `
```

Btw, if you don't want to use lookarounds you could simply use:

```
looking for(.*)player
```

On the other hand, since example 3 contains `here` above regex won't match, so if you want to include that too, you could use this regex:

```
looking (?:for|here)(.*)player
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
(?<=looking for)(?:\s+\S+){1,5}\s+(?=\player)
```

Where `(?:\s+\S+){1,5}` matches one or more spaces followed by one or more non space, repeated one to five times.